# Run A Browser Hidden with Using Php

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, browser, cron

I need to open a page periodically, it includes javascript. Can I run  browser hidden? Because  it is so bad when the page appears. Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: You can use a hidden iframe for your request target o simply use ajax for retrieving the new page, Did you checked ajax?

Comment: phantomjs is usefull, though why are you using php

Comment: You've got a few things mixed up here. Since JavaScript is involved, I guess it should be client-side, but then neither PHP nor cron are relevant here.

Comment: Perhaps if you post what you are actually trying to achieve, someone will be able to point you in the right direction. What is the fundamental problem?

Comment: I wonder , is it possible ? I can make it c# or delphi app run it hidden.

Comment: Olvathar , You misunderstand . Browser is closed. I mean while browser is not working. Already My problem is "run javascript code".

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this by Calling your page in another page in a hidden iframe!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

Just call the programm on your local system with PHP `exec`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Also see what commands your browser force to open a window with the given url.

If you don´t really need to use javascript in it, it´s simpler: Just use curl for it and send some POST/GET data with it, to see from where you refer.